# MS Access check for for last none null

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have the following table - Item and Sizes are the field names:

```
Item  Size1   Size2   Size3  Size4  Size5  Size6  Size7
ABY    S
XYZ    S       M       L      XL
FGH    8       10      12     14
QWE            4       5      6      7
```

But I need to arrive at the following:

```
Item     SizeRange
ABY        S
XYZ        S-XL
FGH        8-14
QWE        4-7
```

I can do this via a `SWITCH` function and checking where size `<> ''` however in reality the fields go up to size 15.  Is there an easier, cleaner way to achieve this? i.e. VBA?

Regards,

Michael

Comment: Use DAO. Open a recordset and loop through the records building an array or collection of the Item names and their size ranges.

Comment: Your data layout is not normalised which is why you are now having problems querying it in a sensible fashion. You should have a table with the Item and a single size column stored vertically. You may want to store an itemsize sort order field with it to determine the way the records are searched and displayed, as the database won't be able to recognise XL is smaller than XXL etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you redesign your table to this format:
[image]

Each size has a weight, or order value so you know which order they're used in.
This SQL, which may not be the best implementation (I'm a little rusty) will give the table shown in your example:

```
SELECT    T1.Item
        , MinSize & IIF(Not MaxSize Is Null,' - ' & MaxSize,'') AS SizeRange
        , MaxSize
FROM    (
            SELECT TOP 1      Item
                            , Size AS MinSize
            FROM              tbl_ItemSizes
            GROUP BY          Item
                            , Size
                            , Weighting
            ORDER BY          Weighting
        ) T1 LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT TOP 1      Item
                            , Size AS MaxSize
            FROM              tbl_ItemSizes
            GROUP BY          Item
                            , Size
                            , Weighting
            ORDER BY          Weighting DESC
        ) T2 ON T1.Item = T2.Item
```

(Someone feel free to rewrite the SQL).

[image]

Comment: ah this looks more like it, I'll see if I can get it working and come back - many thanks.

Comment: Ignore the third field in the in my SQL SELECT (`, MaxSize`); it will just list the Max size for each field and I was meant to remove it.